# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden error

Tags: sharepoint, client-side, sharepoint-2013

I am developing a C# console application on my local computer running on Windows 8. My target SharePoint server is SharePoint Online on Office 365. I am trying to get the web site name using web.Title property of CSOM of SharePoint 2013. I wrote the following code inside the main function to do that.

```
ClientContext clientContext = new    ClientContext("https://innergen.sharepoint.com/sites/mydevsite");
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    clientContext.Load(web);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    Console.WriteLine("Web Site Name : " + web.Title);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Now when I run my project in debug mode, I receive an error saying "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden". I used the same Microsoft Account to log in to both my SharePoint Online account and Windows 8 OS(local machine). Can anybody tell me what's wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think login into the machine with the same SharePoint online account would matter. You still have to use all the remote authentication techniques. See there articles for more details : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh147177.aspx, http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-do-active-authentication-to-Office-365-and-SharePoint-Online.aspx, http://sharepointempower.com/2012/11/remote-authentication-in-sharepoint-onlineoffice-365-using-client-object-model/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add credentials to your clientContext object

```
NetworkCredential credentials =
     new NetworkCredential("username", "pwd", "domain");
clientContext .Credentials = credentials;
```

or use

```
clientContext.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```